# Trying to add a button beside google map search: difficulty align using css and bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

Nothing seems to work!!! 
This is one of the attempts:

I want a search button beside the search bar, in google map. 
the lay out and the code is pretty much line for line from this:

[google maps search example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)

```
<div class="row">
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<button id ="searchspot" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm controls">Search Me</button>
</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

with the css:

```
#map-canvas {
height: 400px;
width: 100%;
}

.row{
display: table-row;
}

.controls {
   ..... (not important)
  }

#pac-input {
....
display: table-cell;
}

#pac-input:focus {
    border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#searchspot {
....
display: table-cell;
}
```

I have also tried float,and inline, which neither of them works. 
Please help.

Comment: If that answered your question, please check the check mark next to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
  //loaded fully

 $('#pac-input').after( '<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>' );

});
```

If you want to keep html out of js.

Put this in your html:

```
  <button id="MapButton" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
```

Then you just use the id's.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
  //loaded fully

 $('#pac-input').after($('#MapButton'));

});
```

Comment: Thank you! I can totally see this working, it looks very awkward though. 
I have a string of call back already, my code is not gonna look nice.

Comment: Are you talking about how your html is in your javascript?

Comment: Not really. I was just worried about the sequence of execution: 
I have a bunch of stuff I want to execute that is ran by 
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load',
and was more worried if the search button would be on top of the marker or something depending on the sequence of which get loaded first. 

But I'll try and see what happens. 
Your advice is been exceedingly helpful!

Comment: No, you are VERY helpful! 
At least now I'm sure there's probably nothing I can do with plain css, bootstrap and have to resort to jQuery. 
You have saved me hours tinkering around!
Thank you!